# Can you assign values to items in HTML5 canvas?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

So essentially I want to create the function below for canvas. Right now this works with any id with elements inside it:

```
$('.class').click(function(){
    var color = prompt('what color would you like to change this stroke to?');
    $('.class').each(function(){
        $(this).css('background-color', color);
    });
});
```

Is there any way to assign values to items in a canvas so that I can trigger what I need, or is this simply impossible?

## Explanation:

If that was unclear...lets say that I add things to my canvas in groups of 10 when I hit a button. If I hit that button 3 times, then I have 3 groups of 10. If I were to click on anything from group 2, then all things in group 2 would have their background-color changed to the one prompted!

Comment: HTML5 Canvas is a drawing element, once drawn, you cannot interact with specific element inside it. However, you could still redraw entire canvas. SVG on the other side let you do interaction with specific elements. A good library for that is raphaelJS: http://raphaeljs.com/

Answer (score 1):

As Canvas is a passive element as in holding the pixels you put there for you not knowing what they are, you need to book-keep everything yourself.

For this you can create objects that holds the vital information such as region and color.

For example (there are a zillion ways to make these, but for simplicity):

```
// ctx = context
function myObject(ctx, x, y, w, h, color) {

    this.render = function() {
        ctx.fillStyle = color;
        ctx.fillRect(x, y, w, h);
    }

    this.setColor = function(newColor) {
        color = newColor;
        this.render();
    }

    this.setPosition = function(newX, newY) {
        x = newX;
        y = newY;
        this.render();
    }
    //... etc. ...
}
```

Now you can create an array, or a stack to keep your objects:

```
var stack = [];
```

When you hit the button:

```
var w = 50, h = 50, i = 0;

for(;i < 10; i++) {
    var o = myObject(ctx, i * w - 2, 0, w, h);
    stack.push(o);
    o.render();
}
```

When you need to update an object you simply call its `setColor` function:

```
//n = index, use a for-loop to update a range (group)
stack[n].setColor(newColor);
```

If you need groups then you can stack them as this:

```
var group = [];
```

Fill group as above, then:

```
stack.push(group);
```

(and you do hit-testing the same way by implementing a method on the object that takes a x and y position and compare with the object's position and width/height).

For memory-efficiency you'd probably want to `prototype` some of the methods (if they don't need access to internal variables and so forth).

Hope that helps.

Comment: +1, but with the hit testing, how will it be able to figure out the group?

Comment: @RyanSaxe you can supply a `groupId` property to your objects.